# Finding the local extrema contour line on a DEM

Tags: qgis, dem

I need to trace the top of a small levee on the side of a riverbank, based on a DEM.

This line is similar to a contour line, except that it goes through the local maximum instead of a constant level.

The local maxima from SAGA returns a point, not a line. I couldn't find any tool to do something similar. Did I miss something?

(for HEC-RAS users, that would allow me to extract a breakline on top of said levee for 2D modeling)

Comment: Is it like detecting ridges? Then you may want to look into Convergence index and other landform classification tools (e.g. TPI-based, Openness-based...)

Comment: I tried to use TPI based landform classification, but it returns a raster, not a line. Though it looks like the structure is recognised, it feels like it's a lot of work to trace a line once the structure is 1 px wide